# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.linalg'

Tags: python, scipy, pip

Bit confused, as the `scipy` package is installed, but still get

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  File "/home/jct/gpu_ready/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/home/jct/gpu_ready/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT
  File "/home/jct/gpu_ready/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "/home/jct/gpu_ready/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan
  File "/home/jct/gpu_ready/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
  File "/home/jct/gpu_ready/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "/home/jct/gpu_ready/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .lgmres import lgmres
  File "/home/jct/gpu_ready/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/lgmres.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import get_blas_funcs, get_lapack_funcs
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.linalg'
```

Also

```
$ pip3 show scipy
Name: scipy
Version: 1.4.1
Summary: SciPy: Scientific Library for Python
Home-page: https://www.scipy.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /home/jct/gpu_ready/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: numpy
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running Python 3.X?

Comment: Yes ` python --version` -> `Python 3.6.3`

Comment: Inside your script, can you print `scipy.__version__` ?

Comment: How did you install `scipy`? What does `pip3 show scipy -f | grep -i linalg` output?

Comment: Installed scipy with pip3, same for all other packages I installed.
That command returns a long list of `scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/...` and `scipy/linalg/...`